# Are there modern airplanes with two propellers driven by one single engine?

Tags: aircraft-design, engine, propulsion

Except 1903 Wright flyer, are there any other airplane using one single engine driving two coplanar propellers?

- Coplanar means push-pull and coaxial designs are not in the question's frame.
- Tilt rotor aircraft that able to fly with one engine driving two rotors in case of an engine failure are also outside the question's frame.

Edit: I recently came across an example of such a configuration, in this [video](https://youtu.be/XZ29JDBNmKg?si=ge4J9lj-MAZ0CZ2v&t=556) mentioning the [André Starck's AS-37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starck_AS-37), powered by a 60hp Citroën GS engine driving two propellers.

[image]

([source](https://www.secretprojects.co.uk/data/attachments/80/80706-8af2967bce7f3155c410a6668811e1f1.jpg))

[image]

(printscreen from above video)

Comment: It has not flown, but the research project Idintos envisaged using a central engine to propel two shrouded propellers on the sides of the fuselage (see bottom image of [this page](http://www.idintos.eu/eng/?page_id=118)).

Comment: I seem to recall a 1930's or 40's design with wing-mounted pusher engines driven by shafts connected to an engine or engines in the fuselage, but can't come up with any more details--

Comment: @Gypaets if you make it an answer i'll upvote and accept it (unless if someone finds something more amazingly matching in the days to come) since it's a great find, and by the way a great project.

Comment: Do helicopters using one engine to spin the main rotor and tail rotor count?

Comment: @nick012000 no i'm looking for airplanes

Comment: @Gypaets was it even prototyped to full scale? I can only find references to the wind tunnel models. +1 for the find, though.

Comment: @AEhere They presented a full scale model at the [AERO 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAJXV7XK91k)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NASA has proposed to use single gas generator cores to mechanically drive multiple fans in various advanced vehicle concepts, but those are a long way from actually being built.

[image]

[image]

Airbus and others are also proposing [hybrid-electric airlines](https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/press-releases/en/2019/05/airbus-and-sas-scandinavian-airlines-sign-hybrid-and-electric-aircraft-research-agreement.html) where a few gas generator cores drive many small fans, although in that case the power is electrically distributed rather than mechanically linked. There are some hybrid-electric vehicles in development that might qualify (Airbus E-Fan-X, UTC 804).  With all the current development in electric aircraft, it is likely some vehicle that meets your description will fly in the near future, with the caveat that the linkage between the engine and multiple propellers is likely to be electrical and not mechanical.

Images from [NASA](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20100036222.pdf)